# Android Child Activity Canvas Size Width Limited

Tags: android, android-activity, resize, width, android-canvas

I have written an app with a main activity GUI consisting of multiple buttons and text views within a relative layout specified by an XML layout file. It occupies approximately half the landscape width and two thirds the height.

I wish to call a child activity with a full screen canvas that, when activated, would cover up the then paused main activity GUI.

I have made a separate app that uses an onDraw(Canvas) class called DrawView that provides,  when run as a stand alone app, the full screen canvas that I want. It is constructed from an activity with the code that is shown below.

The problem I have is that when I merge this code into my main package and start the canvas activity from the main activity the window width for the canvas is reduced from 1280 to 696 pixels according to the getWidth() method. It appears my parent main activity limits the child activity window size. I don't know what is causing this width reduction nor how to control it. I have tried many options to no avail. How do I prevent this width reduction from happening? Is it controlled by an Android scheme? Can this be overridden?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set full screen view
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(drawView);
        drawView.requestFocus();
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);            
    }
```

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question here just in case there is someone else who is new to I imagine common high level graphics terminology runs into this same problem.

All I needed to do was remove the manifest file "themes" line for this activity which was:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"

The Dialog theme limits the size of the Activity window to a typical user input dialog screen size.